# How to Make Responsive Bootstrap 3 Pagination

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This:
[image]

Turns in to this on smaller viewports:

[image]

*I think it looks yucky and it takes up a lot of space too.*

**This is standard pagination html:**

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="text-center">
          <ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
             <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
             <li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>
             <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">13</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">14</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">15</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">16</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Now, I could use smaller versions with the classes they provide, however everything -- no matter what -- should be friendly for **fat fingers** because some touch devices just as big as desktop devices.

Comment: Hallo Lady what is this? and why are you answering you own (question) is it a kind of tutorial ?

Comment: @Tambo http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Christina i know that what i am asking is, are you looking for some help or are you just posting this to help others?

Comment: @Tambo: It's not uncommon to answer your own questions. I do it a lot since I care more than anyone else. Yes, it's to help others.

Comment: Rather, I do it if I know the answer, sometimes I don't.

Comment: ok thank you that is what i wanted to know and thank you for the answer too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my opinion toggling the pagination is a helper but not the final solution. I found a bootstrap plugin that does exactly what I expect pagination to do at smaller screen sizes - it shrinks the number of paginated li chunks to match the screen width like this:

[image: wide screen size]
[image: medium screen size]
[image: small screen size]

[rPage - responsive bootstrap3 pagination plugin](http://auxiliary.github.io/rpage/)

Comment: Yes! That is much better than what I came up with. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Functionally awesome. But, on mobile, this plugin was causing some serious lagging, for me.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `class="hidden-xs"`:

#### Normal

```
< 1 2 3 4 [5] 6 7 8 9 10 >
```

#### Small

```
< 4 [5] 6 >
```

#### Example in php

```
if($number != $page) { echo ' class="hidden-xs" '; }
```

Answer (score 6):

## DEMO: http://jsbin.com/cotopu/1

[image]

**CSS:**

```
/* pagination-responsive */
@media (min-width:0px) and (max-width:650px) { 
    .toggle-pagination {
        display: block
    }
    .toggle-pagination.active i:before {
        content: '\2212'
    }
    .pagination-responsive {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 10px;
        display: none;
    }
    .pagination-responsive > li > a,
    .pagination-responsive > li > span {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 40px;
        padding: 0;
        border-radius: 0px!important;
    }
    .pagination-responsive > li {
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        margin-top: -1px;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
@media (max-width:480px) { 
    .pagination-responsive > li {
        width: 33%
    }
}
@media (max-width:320px) { 
    .pagination-responsive > li {
        width: 50%
    }
}
@media (min-width:651px) { 
    .toggle-pagination {
        display: none
    }
    .pagination-responsive {
        display: inline-block!important
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="text-center">
     <a class="btn btn-default btn-block toggle-pagination"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Toggle Pagination</a>
      <ul class="pagination pagination-responsive pagination-lg">
         <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
         <li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>
         <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">13</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">14</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">15</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">16</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// show-pagination
    $('.toggle-pagination').click(function(f) {
        $(this).next('.pagination-responsive').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        f.preventDefault()
    });
});
```

Comment: I noticed putting two within the same container back to back, they'd overlap. Thought it was a JS problem at first but ended up needing to add 

`.pagination-responsive {
  overflow: hidden;
}`

to the css. Was putting two on a page to see if that would work, incase I ever did one at the top and another one on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The following will do the trick. Pagination will be responsive on all devices with same amount of pages.

```
.pagination {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.pager li, .pagination>li {
    display: inline;
    display: table-cell;
}
.pagination>li>a,
.pagination>li>span {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Additionally you can play with `.hidden-xs`, `.hidden-md` classes or with `@media` queries to get more flexibility.